# Batch Change Raster Symbology from Stretch to Unique values using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology

I know how to set the Symbology for several rasters at a time using batch Apply Symbology from Layer. But this only works if the Symbology type is the same for the Symbology layer and Input layers.

I have 600 rasters that when added to ArcGIS Pro 2.8 automatically display with Stretched symbology. As the rasters are categorical, I would like to view all of them with the same Unique Value symbology.

Is there a way to convert the Symbology of all 600 rasters from Stretched to Unique values?

I'd like to apply the same color scheme to all 600 rasters without having to individually change each ones' symbology to Unique values. I tried with Apply Symbology from Layer but of course receive an error since the Symbology layer was Unique values while the Input layers are Stretched.

An alternative approach I tried that I think should work (but isn't) was to keep the Symbology type as Stretched, but apply a discrete color scheme instead of continuous to one raster. Then use batch Apply to the rest of the ~600 rasters. I tested this by changing the Symbology layer back to stretched and assigning the color scheme I want via Discrete color scheme, then using that one to Apply Symbology from layer to two test rasters via the Apply tool in batch. For whatever reason in the map, ArcGIS Pro is only displaying one of the output rasters with the color scheme. It shows up in the Table of Contents for all three (one input and two outputs) with the correct colors, but for two of the .tifs (the inital Symbology layer that I manually assigned the desired Symbology to then used with the tool, and one of the output .tifs), the map is only displaying the default grayscale stretched symbology. No clue why that is.

Comment: What format are your rasters, you say they load as a stretch and that would imply they are float format, categorical or unique values are integer rasters. It's not clear from your question what they are?

Comment: @Hornbydd my rasters are 8bit, but load as stretch (values of 0 and 1). I would like them all to be displayed with a specific color key via unique values, but neither apply symbology nor apply colormap is working despite them being 8bit int. it's thousands of images so no way i can manually change them all

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data along with the layer file that has the unique value rendering? I think it will be difficult for people to offer up a solution without test data.

Comment: If you change Pro's default symbology to unique prior to adding them to a project will that allow you to then use your batch apply symbology from a layer?  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/set-raster-and-imagery-default-options.htm